# How to copy a file in the time stamp folder

Tags: python, linux, timestamp, mkdir

I make a directory with the current timestamp 12:32:57 PM. I want to copy the file to the time folder who can I do this? I run the following code

```
import os  
import shutil 

cmd_mkdir = 'mkdir /home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/ros_bag_saved/"$(date +%r)"'
os.system(cmd_mkdir)

origin_past=f'/home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/rosbag/1.bag'
target_past=f'/home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/ros_bag_saved/$(date +%r)/1.bag'
shutil.copy(origin_past,target_past)
```

Comment: Sidenotes: There's an [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.html#os.mkdir). Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build the target path-string. The target path string for `shutil.copy` doesn't have to include the filename if you don't want to change it (which seems to be the case).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is grab the time in python and save it in a variable, that way you can reference the same time for both creating the folder and copying the file into it.

You could use

```
import os
import shuitil
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
```

This will get the time in the format you have above (ie 12:32:57 PM)

Then update your commands to use it:

```
cmd_mkdir = f'mkdir /home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/ros_bag_saved/{time}'
target_past = f'/home/mubashir/catkin_ws/src/germany1_trush/ros_bag_saved/{time}/1.bag'
```